# Zephir build throws "exhausted allowed memory size" on newly cloned Phalcon repo

Tags: memory-leaks, phalcon, zephir

#### General

```
software: MacOS
Phalcon: 5.0.x
PHP: 8.1
Zephir: 0.16.0
brew: phalcon@4.1.0
Location: ~/Documents/cphalcon
```

#### Details

I have just cloned phalcon following the instructions [here](https://docs.phalcon.io/5.0/en/installation#compilation).
I have already installed zhephir_phar and set up zephir.phar to make it executable.
Then I cloned the repo and ran these:

```
cd cphalcon/
git checkout tags/v5.0.0 ./
zephir fullclean
zephir build
```

However the second command throws

```
error: pathspec 'tags/v5.0.0' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

(and there is indeed no folder named tags)
As for the fourth command, (`zephir build`) throws:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32768 bytes) in phar:///usr/local/bin/zephir/Library/Statements/ForStatement.php on line 631

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32768 bytes) in phar:///usr/local/bin/zephir/Library/Statements/ForStatement.php on line 631
```

This is a newly cloned repo, and I have not yet changed anything.
Any clues as to what is throwing this error?

### Update

(I removed the update, as it did not have any connection to the fix for this issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### fix

I tried the following steps, and it worked!

1. I downloaded the repo from here (cloning the repo will probably work fine too): https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/releases/tag/v5.0.0RC4
2. I ran the following (note that `zephir compile` will take a long time):

```
cd cphalcon/
zephir fullclean
zephir compile
cd ext
phpize
./configure
make && make install
cd ..
zephir install
```

3. And added the `extension="phalcon.so"` inside the php.ini file.
4. I restarted the webserver:

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

5. Finally I created the files `public/index.php` and `.htrouter.php` as instructed [here](https://docs.phalcon.io/5.0/en/webserver-setup), and started the webserver:

```
$(which php) -S localhost:8000 -t public .htrouter.php
```

### more

It seems the only issue was with `zephir generate`. The framework seemed to work perfectly fine so long ad I skipped that command (`zephir build` ran `zephir generate` as well).
But this might be more of a way to avoid the issue rather than fixing it...

Answer (score 1):

These are the commands that I used to install the latest Phalcon 5.0.0RC3:

```
cd /usr/local/lib
git clone -b 5.0.x https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon
cd cphalcon
zephir fullclean
zephir build
phpenmod phalcon
```

Do keep in mind that Phalcon five is still a release candidate and has not been finalized yet.  The Phalcon team hopes to have the final release out by the end of August.

Comment: I see, I tried following your steps, but still get the same error. I only chose Phalcon 5 because I have php 8.1 installed. I am not exactly in a hurry, do you recommend I wait for their finalized version?

Comment: You don't need to wait if you are getting up and running on Phalcon and don't need to put your code live in production right now.  For example, I have four products in Phalcon and I am migrating three of them now to Phalcon 5, so testing with the release candidate of Phalcon 5 if acceptable to me.

Comment: Alright, I will try to see what is causing this error. I'll update the question if I find anything new :)